# prevent web directory from opening the linked website content on its page

Tags: web, directory

I submitted the URL of my website to a web directory, but to my surprise, it is showing my content in its page with ads to garner more traffic. I want to prevent the web directory website to show my website contents on its website. Please guide

Comment: What "contents" is the site showing? If it's just a link to your page, there's nothing you can do about that. If they are hot linking content, you can block that.

Comment: I write for a job portal.The website claims to be a web directory but instead it is showing the posts of my page. I am giving the url:http://www.trendaajkal.com/government-jobs/english/jobsnia-com-english.html

Comment: Can you provide a link of the directory you submitted to so I can better understand

Comment: www,trendaajkal.com was supposed to be web directory as it declared, whereas it is showing my content, with ads. I write for www.jobsnia.com and i am the administrator. Please guide as i want to stop www.trendaajkal.com from doing this.

Comment: http://www.trendaajkal.com/

Comment: Please guide as there might be some way to come out of this website or blocking the website from doing this

Comment: I posted the answer..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they're using an iframe to link content. Try adding this script to your page

**Updated Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(document.referrer.indexOf("trendaajkal.com") != -1) {
        window.location = "http://jobsnia.com/";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanking you Sir. It is working fine. Really many many many thanks. Thank you

Comment: I added this script in header.php of my wordpress site   <script type="text/javascript">
if ( window.self !== window.top ) {
    window.top.location.href=window.location.href;
}
</script> But now I am unable to customise the theme of my website. please guide

Comment: What is it doing?

Comment: whenever I try to customise my theme, like changing site title, logo etc.  I click on the customise option on my dashboard. It immediately puts me out.  in the logged condition in the dashboard.of course, it is not logging me off but simply stopping me only to customize the theme.

Comment: The updated script did not work. Any way I am continuing with the youtube linked script you suggested earlier. Thanks